# Side by side boxplot with correct legend labels in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am creating a side-by-side boxplot that is colored by hex colors. I seem to have it working, but am unable to get the legend (on the right of the plot) to have the cut labels (Ex: "Fair" instead of "#F8766D"). Here is a MWE that mimics my problem:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)

df <- diamonds[sample(1:nrow(diamonds), size = 1000),]
colList = scales::hue_pal()(5)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
df <- df %>% select("cut","price")
saveColor <- df %>% transmute(color = plyr::mapvalues(cut, c("Fair", "Good", "Very Good", "Premium", "Ideal"), colList))
df$color <- unlist(saveColor)

ggplot(df, aes(cut, price)) + geom_boxplot(aes(fill = factor(color))) + scale_colour_manual(labels = c("Fair", "Good", "Very Good", "Premium", "Ideal"), values = colList)
```

[image]

Comment: I wonder if you just want to change `scale_colour_manual()` to `scale_fill_manual()`.

Comment: @jazzurro Yes, that fixes the problem, though the code is still overly complicated. There's no need to add the colors into the data frame.

Comment: @ClausWilke Yeah I see your point. I just wanted to point out a quick way to fix the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what exactly it is that you're trying to do, but in general you wouldn't add the colors as a column into the dataset. Instead, you just provide them as values to the color scale. Also note how much simpler that makes your code.

```
df <- diamonds[sample(1:nrow(diamonds), size = 1000),]
colList = scales::hue_pal()(5)
df <- df %>% select("cut","price")
ggplot(df, aes(cut, price)) + 
  geom_boxplot(aes(fill = cut)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(values = colList)
```

[image]